# How to put div above another div and increase height of background div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, fullscreen

I am new to html and css. I have seen this question asked many times but I can't seems to get it working to fit my problem .

I have 3 div tags. when the user swipe the top div tag I want the the bottom div tag to increase its height and cause the web page to scroll. then move all the div tags align at the top.

The reason I am doing this is; this will cause webpage running on a mobile to go to full screen.

```
  <div id="backExpander" style="height: 100%; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
  </div>
  <div id="canvasHolder" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;background-color: transparent;">
  <canvas id="GameCanvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" tabindex="0"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div id="swipeUpHolder" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display:block;"  >
  </div>
```

The script I am using is;

```
document.getElementById("swipeUpHolder").addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, {passive: false});

function onTouchMove(e)
{
  e.preventDefault

  document.getElementById("backExpander").style.height = "120%";
 
  setTimeout((function() {
                
        document.getElementById("swipeUpHolder").style.display = "none";
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          }
        ), 50);
}
```

As you can see I am increasing the height of background div but it does not do anything.

if I increase height of top div, this will work

```
document.getElementById("swipeUpHolder").style.height = "120%";
```

But I want to hide the top div. use the bottom div to push the page to go into scroll.

Can anyone provide some advice on how to fix this  ?

Comment: have you tried using `vh` instead of percentages for your dimensions?

Comment: I am not much familiar with css or html. Have not used vh before. How do I use it?

Comment: just use it as your unit (e.g. `height: 120vh;`) `120vh`'s gonna take 120 viewport height. More on it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-units-em-rem-px-vh-vw/

Comment: @YongPin tried it. It has no effect. Maybe what we need to change is display: inline-block; position: relative;  tags?

Comment: if you set the height for `#backExpander` to `100vh` instead of `100%` and remove the `display: inline-block;` property then it will work.

Comment: also add some `background` to your `div`'s so you can visually track the changes.

Comment: Changed it like that. Still no change   <div id="backExpander" style="height: 100vh; color: blue; position: relative;">
  </div>
  <div id="canvasHolder" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;background-color: transparent;">
  <canvas id="GameCanvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" tabindex="0"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="swipeUpHolder" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display:block;"  >
  </div>

Comment: Can anyone provide some advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is your original code w/ background colors:

```js
document.getElementById("swipeUpHolder").addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, {
  passive: false
});

function onTouchMove(e) {
  e.preventDefault

  document.getElementById("backExpander").style.height = "120%";

  setTimeout((function() {

    document.getElementById("swipeUpHolder").style.display = "none";
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }), 50);
}
```

```html
<div id="backExpander" style="height: 100%; display: inline-block; position: relative; background: blue;">
</div>
<div id="canvasHolder" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;background-color: red;">
  <canvas id="GameCanvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" tabindex="0"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="swipeUpHolder" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display:block;">
</div>
```

This is when you use `vh` units for your dimension on `#backExpander`:

```js
document.getElementById("swipeUpHolder").addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, {
  passive: false
});

function onTouchMove(e) {
  e.preventDefault
  document.getElementById("backExpander").style.height = "120%";
  setTimeout((function() {
    document.getElementById("swipeUpHolder").style.display = "none";
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }), 50);
}
```

```html
<div id="backExpander" style="height: 100vh; position: relative; background: blue;">
</div>
<div id="canvasHolder" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: red;">
  <canvas id="GameCanvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" tabindex="0"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="swipeUpHolder" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display:block;">
</div>
```